# ckeditor 4.3.3 height attributes doesnt work

Tags: jquery, height, ckeditor

I'm having an issue with the height attribute in ckeditor. I cant get it to set at all.
The width works ok.. 
I am doing all the normal things

- loading ckeditor in the head
- placing the CKEDITOR.replace code after the textarea

For now I am trying to set the height in the default config.js but I am not having any success. Width works but height doesnt.. I have even tried to include the height in the CKEDITOR.replace code but still no joy.

Same issue in IE11, Firefox and Chrome

Comment: Some code would help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try any of  following

```
config.height = 500;        // 500 pixels.
config.height = '25em';     // CSS length.
config.height = '300px';    // CSS length.
```

as mentioned in api docs @ http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config

Answer (score 0):

It may be possibility as you have used height in replace method. and you are trying to set in config..

Referred Link: [https://ckeditor.com/old/forums/Support](https://ckeditor.com/old/forums/Support/how-change-height-for-one-ckeditor-not-all)

I did like this for my **A4 page** Size.

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'template_ckeditor', {

    width: '210mm', 
    height: '297mm'
} );
```